# Will Select Statement Block other sessions - Oracle 12.1

Tags: oracle, session, block, oracle12.1

Hello all, 
So far my understanding was Select Statement will not cause blocking other sessions, i am experiencing the block session due to Select statement in Oracle 12.1 version .

Here is my example ,

I have a procedure that has insert into target table statement like below

`Insert Into Target_tab select columns from source_tab1, source_tab2 , source_tab3 Join Condition` 

 at the same time , in different sessions DML operations are happening on the source_tab1, source_tab2 , source_tab3

In this scenario The DML operations are slowed down and many session waiting for the select statement to complete for inserting data into Target_Tab Table.


The first query is just a Select statement but blocking other sessions, Please give your view why  Block is happening for select statements, Thanks in advance .

Comment: "slowed down" is not the same as "blocking", which would return an error. a query can require disk i/o to retrieve data, which can absolutely slow down other queries or DML operations that also require disk i/o. are you getting an error back saying that a transaction has been blocked and cannot be executed, or is it just slow? if you are getting an error returned, please include that and examples of all of the queries and DML statements affected in your question. as it is, you haven't really provided enough information to do more than guess what is going on.

Comment: A select will not block your DML. The *insert* however might. Is there a foreign key on target_tab that refers to source_tab1, source_tab2 or source_tab3? If so, then an insert into the child table (target_tab) will block deletes on those parent table(s). Also check that there are no insert triggers on target_tab that are doing other DML somewhere. Lastly, verify that the waiting sessions are in fact blocked on the target_tab insert and not something else. Did you check the blocking session info in v$session to verify? What was the wait event on which the source DML sessions were stuck?

Comment: [Summary of Locking Behavior](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/data-concurrency-and-consistency.html#GUID-1D60EFCC-03F4-4A04-B099-1B4DE5D02C47): - *A row is locked only when modified by a writer.* - *A reader never blocks a writer.* - *A writer never blocks a reader.*